# Javascript Web Worker isn't getting message

Tags: javascript, multithreading, promise, web-worker

I have a web worker that's running a long-running calculation.  I've split the calculation up to run in a chain of `Promise`s, so several times per second, the thread has a chance to do something else before continuing with the calculation.

I want to be able to cancel the calculation by sending a message.  Using `Worker.terminate()` kills the calculation, but doesn't free up the memory, and I'm running into browser crashes.

```
function calculate() {
    // case when no dice are being calculated
    if (!_diceList.length) {
        _finished = true;
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    let promise = Promise.resolve();
    // create chain of promise calculations
    for (let i = 0; i < _totalPermutations; i += PERMUTATIONS_PER_BREAK) {
        promise = promise.then(() => {
            if (!_shouldContinue || _finished) {
                return;
            } else {
                reportStatus();
                _atBreak = false;
                calculateRecursive();
            }
        });
    }

    return promise;
}

// ...

function run(data) {
    setup(data.dice);

    calculate().then(() => {
        reportStatus();
    }).catch(() => true).then(() => {
        close(); 
    });
}

onmessage = function (e) {
    if (e.data === 'cancel') {
        _shouldContinue = false;
    } else {
        run(e.data);
    }
};
```

When I debug, I can see that the code that creates the `Worker` does send the `'cancel'` message, but when I set a breakpoint in my `onmessage` in the Worker code, it never enters the function.

I know that JavaScript is single-threaded, but I thought the entire purpose of Promises was to simulate async behavior.

Comment: What browser and what promise library are you using?

Comment: Promise callbacks probably run before any message events, not interleaved with them.

Comment: Chrome's built in one.  I hid it, but I polyfill with es6-promise.

Comment: **async !== parallell**, promises not simulate async (async not need to be simulated) they just add you a way to resolve your async functions in any place where they run.

you can't change variable in same flow.  if you need ability to cancel function without adittional  worker, you should go out from flow time to time.

what happen here ? onmessage handler runs after calculate() done. :)